Using Python for Excel to loop values in Excel-range
I have a hard time getting started with Python for Excel, writing Python formulas in Excel-cells. A stripped down version of my use case is as follows: In B2:B3 I have yearly growth rates, here set at 10 percent. I would like to calculate the accumulated growth. In a traditional formula, this would be (1+b2)*(1+b3)-1, approximately 21 percent. I also added them in a factor form in c2:c3, so the same calculation would be c2*c3-1.
But I would like to use the new Python for Excel-feature for this. I have inserted the following simple Python-snippet into a PY()-formula in B4, but it returns 0. It seems to skip the for-loop without errors or warnings of any kind.
tot = 1
for yearly in xl("B2:B3"):
   tot *= (1+yearly)
tot-1

I also tried looping over arr = xl("B2:B3", convert=list), in an attempt to make the range iterable. I had no luck.
So how do I do this?
Sheet:


It is a number value formatted as percent and behaves normally when using ordinary Excel formulas. I also tried changing the formatting, but it doesn't affect the Python-formula.

Sure. Updated the post. But as I said, changing the format doesn't alter the result of the Python for Excel-calculation. European number formatting btw, so comma is a decimal separator.

No, I don't think so. "return" raises a SyntxError. And a value is returned, just not the value I was expecting. It's kind of like a Jupyter Notebook, in that a value on the bottom row is automatically returned (to the cell, in this case). Note that there is no use of return in Microsofts quite limited examples: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-python-in-excel-a33fbcbe-065b-41d3-82cf-23d05397f53d

Yeah. Also, I believe I figured it out. The xl-function, even when the convert-parameter is set to "list", is a Pandas dataframe, and the iteration can be done by
arr=xl("B2:B3")
tot=1
for index, row in arr.iterrows():
tot*=(1+row[0])
tot-1
This works, but it is far from elegant

The xl()-function returns a Pandas dataframe.
Hence, it can be iterated over by the following (adapted from this post):
arr=xl("B2:B3")
tot=1
for index, row in arr.iterrows():
    tot*=(1+row[0])
tot-1

or, as looping each row isn't really necessary when it is a df, the same can be done by
arr=xl("B2:B3")
tot=(arr[0]+1).product()
tot-1


Hei, with pandas.DataFrame.iloc — pandas 2.2.3 documentation tot = 1 for yearly in xl("B2:B3").iloc[:,0]:    tot *= (1+yearly) tot-1
